# Installing Netflix in Xubuntu, any luck?

Tags: wine, xubuntu, xfce, netflix

I am working in Xubuntu right now, and am having a tough time installing the Netflix Desktop.

I have tried the method mentioned in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tfte5su5DIA), which from my understanding, is simply the only way to install it. After the terminal says the install is done, I can't find Netflix Desktop anywhere, even when I search my applications.

Does this program simply not work in Xubuntu? Anyone have had any luck running it?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to say 'OK' to the ttf fonts installer? Someone  commented that the video didn't explain this.

Comment: Took me a moment, but I was able to tab over to the "yes" button, but still no application. Do I need wine already installed?

Comment: Xubuntu is a distribution for older, slower machines, and running Netflix under wine isn't likely to be a satisfactory experience on an older, slower system.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command

```
netflix-desktop
```

in the terminal. If this works, create a bash script that is something simple like:

```
#!/bin/bash
netflix-desktop
```

and put it on your desktop. In the terminal again

```
cd ~/Desktop
chmod +x your-script
```

Now, you can click on the bash file to start Netflix.

I had the same problem with my desktop Netflix install, but this has saved me a lot of time and hassle.